# Area - vertical closing stroke line

Tags: reactjs, recharts

[image: area chart]]

How to add a vertical line to look like on the picture?

Answer (score 0):

`<ComposedChart data={data} barCategoryGap={0}>` this might help

To leave the space between: Add some data **equal to 0**

Comment: to have only one line, it may need a chart rendering link these where you add logic to the styling (example at the start don't add stroke at the left .... at the end add to the right, etc ... LOGIC RENDERING), more on the documentation.
`data.map((entry, index) => <Cell cursor="pointer" ...style... / >`
It may not be possible to style it completely like that, but you may get some of it.